# How to upgrade my MySQL version to 5.7.7 or higher in Xampp 3.2.2 (latest version), errors in Laravel MySQL migration

Tags: mysql, xampp, laravel-5.4

My Laravel cannot migrate the tables giving an error of:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))

I got a solution [in this link](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error), but it is also not working, so I decided to upgrade my MySql to 5.7.7 or higher as the blog says that I won't face any problems then.

I am using Windows 10. Here is a screenshot of my phpMyAdmin:

[image: Phpmyadmin]

Here is my error screen:

[image: My error screen]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Ok I get it, and thanks halfer for editing

Answer (score 0):

follow this line steps

you just add 2 lines on AppServiceProvider.php

https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Comment: I had already used this link, and it is also mentioned in my question as 'this link'